# IStringLocalizer in console application

Tags: localization, .net-core, console-application

Having a library contains *resx* files and using this document [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and adding following codes in Startup.cs we localized our web application:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(option =>
    {
        option.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof({the-resx-library}));
    })
    .AddViewLocalization()
```

In controllers:

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<{the-resx-library}> _localizer;
public AccountController(IStringLocalizer<{the-resx-library}> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string text = this._localizer["Hello"];
    return View();
}
```

The question is how can we use that *resx* library in a **console application**? That console application generates content based on user's chosen language and email it.

Answer (score 1):

I used [localization-culture-core](https://github.com/Wolox/localization-culture-core), and the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console package.

You can then create a resource folder and add your culture specific resource files in json.
e.g.

[image: resources]

These contain resource key value pair string e.g.

```
{"SayHi": "Hello", "SayBye" : "Bye"}
```

Then use it like this :

```
public class Someclass
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public Someclass()
    {

        ILogger logger = new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLogger("", null, false);
        _localizer = (IStringLocalizer)new JsonStringLocalizer("Resources", "TestLocalization", logger);
    }

    public void Talk()
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
        Console.WriteLine(_localizer.GetString("SayHi"));
    }
}
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: While this answer might help, it doesn't seem to really address the question of how to use .resx files in a console application.. It instead proposes switching to using .json files.